# Create Android app release mode

Tags: android, release

I want to create my Android app in release mode.  I did the suggested Export from Eclipse.  Android tools -> Export Unassigned ( then signed it aligned it etc ) I though the export would give me release mode app.  I checked on disk and the .apk is just the same size as the one I get when I normally compile in Eclipse.
Further I installed it in the emulator by >adb install myapp.apk then I tried to attach to the application in the Eclipse debugger and sure enough it hit my breakpoint.  So I'm convinced I have indeed a debug version.  The question is how can I create release mode version of my application from Eclipse before signing and submitting to the market place ?

### Edit

If I log it the debuggable flag is off when exported, as well when running from Eclipse. Unless I explicitly set it to true in the Manifest application section. It seems the debug / release mode is just a flag on / off. Doesn't do anything more than that, I can set breakpoints and debug both versions. The resulting .apk is the same size.

```
cxLog.e( "TOKEN", " Debuggable=" + (( context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo( comp.getPackageName(), 0 ).flags &= ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE ) != 0 ) );
```

> 10-28 14:46:12.479: ERROR/TOKEN(1856): Debuggable=false

Comment: Good question.  I am new to android development, and it seems to me what should be a one click process (export in release mode), is actually a horrendous compendium of options, editing the code to remove Log calls, optimizing (or not) etc etc.  Perhaps a sign of lack of mature leadership in the Android dev team.  I see this is marked as answered - but what is the solution?  I am on SDK 16, and am hitting the same issues...  I started with reading the Android docs - so links back to that have not helped me...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> The question is how can I create release mode version of my application from Eclipse

Check this out : [Compile the application in the release mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#releasecompile)

> Android Tools > Export Unsigned Application Package

---

> [Support for a true debug build](http://developer.android.com/sdk/tools-notes.html). Developers no longer need to add the android:debuggable attribute to the tag in the manifest — the build tools add the attribute automatically. In Eclipse/ADT, all incremental builds are assumed to be debug builds, so the tools insert android:debuggable="true". When exporting a signed release build, the tools do not add the attribute. In Ant, a ant debug command automatically inserts the android:debuggable="true" attribute, while ant release does not. If android:debuggable="true" is manually set, then ant release will actually do a debug build, rather than a release build.

Comment: What happen if i use "Export Signed Application Package" will it auto sign my apps and zipallign it?

Comment: @Orn hmm the documentation says something else, which version of SDK are you using, Also try to use ProGuard, maybe that can remove unwanted debug symbols?

Comment: @xDragonZ  Jepp, it will do exactly that.

Comment: My Android sdk is at 7, seems 15 is out already, maybe time to update

Comment: Also try "Select the project in the Package Explorer and select File > Export." from http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#ExportWizard worked for me.

Comment: @xDragonZ - yes, according to [Compile and sign with Eclipse ADT](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#ExportWizard): "Complete the Export Wizard and your application will be compiled, signed, aligned, and ready for distribution."

Answer (score 4):

If you want to SIGNED IN and ZIP ALIGNED your app in release mode so that it could distribute and can be uplodated to the Google play store, then just follow the below steps.

```
 --> Right click on project
 --> Android Tools
 --> Export Unassigned app and save in directory like D:\Sdcard.apk

         //Now open your windows terminal, CMD
 --> change directory to the bin of the jave like
 --> cd c:\ProgramFiles\JAVA\JDK\bin
```

Now this is time to create **Keystore Released File**...
now write these commands in the TERMINAL,

> > keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 14600

This will propmt for **Keystore** "password" and for **Key** "password", so type different password and answer to the question it will ask later.
Now  **my-release-key.keystore** file will be generated in directory where your "bin" folder of java are, like in my sytstem it will be like

```
     c:\ProgramFiles\JAVA\JDK\bin\ my-release-key.keystore
```

write this command in Terminal for Signed in the app

> > jarsigner -verbose -keystore  my-release-key.keystore D:\Sdcard.apk mykey

Now redirect your terminal to the Zipalign.exe file which is located in Android sdk 21\tool\ , like in my system i did that

> cd F:\Softwares\LANGUAGES SOFTEARE\Android Setup\android-sdk-21 version\tools

After that put the below line in the terminal

> > zipalign -v 4 D:\Sdcard.apk newSdcard.apk

Congratulations! - Now you will find a `newSdcard.apk` file inside the Android sdk\tool, Now upload it to play store, and remember me with love.

Comment: `Right click on project` where exactly 'project' is situated?

Comment: @fnc12 yes the project which you have in eclipse, Just right click on it and the follow the above step

Comment: @fnc12 pirfahimshah1 ,  its my skype if you have any problem you can catch me there

Comment: what about Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

On current versions of the Android SDK, just right-click the project, Android Tools > Export Signed Application Package, and select your keystore