# Android prevent users from stack tracing an application

Tags: php, android

I recently uploaded an application on Google play store, this app connects to an online server using a php page. While I'm checking crashes and ANRs in developers console I found a crash written by a user, this user was able to trace the error like he was using the logcat in eclipse. He managed to get the link of the php page with the given parameters. 
In my code, I deleted everything that is related to Log.

My question is how can I prevent users from tracing the errors in my application ?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924173/create-android-app-release-mode

Comment: Thank you @Raptor I'll read it

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want your exceptions (and hence exception stack trace) to be thrown from your application, set a global uncaught exception handler.

[`Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29)

Do it in your `Application` sub-class and handle the exceptions appropriately. Make sure you terminate process gracefully after you've handled the exception.

You could also opt for third-party crash reporting mechanisms like [ACRA](http://acra.ch/), [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/flurry-crash-analytics.html), [BugSense](https://www.bugsense.com/), etc.