# Create a release build with Android with custom builders

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to add a custom builders that will generate some configuration for the app depends on whether it's a debug or release build. XCode makes it clear between Debug and Release build but in Eclipse is not so. I'm even unable to find a way to know whether it's a Debug or Release build inside my custom Builders.

So my question:

1. How to specify a Debug/Release build for an android project? (perhaps this article somehow explained that: [Create Android app release mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924173/create-android-app-release-mode))
2. How to know that it's a Debug/Release build in my custom Builder?

Comment: So I'm still expecting a decent way to achieve this. In the mean time I do a work around by manually echo-ing a value indicating whether the build is Debug/Release to a text file and read that value from my build script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Gradle, you can refer [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Type-Product-Flavor-Build-Variant)

Comment: Just have a brief look. Gradle look like an overkill to me. I already have everything setup with regular eclipse build and just need a way to figure out whether a build is for release or not inside my custom Builder.

Comment: Links are not answers. Answers on SO are expected to be self-contained. Please [review this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/135887)  and add enough detail to your answer to make it not completely reliant on an external link.